# Combining data in in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

I want to take the Mean column values for the year, add them then take the average. eg I would combine indexes 0-5

(175.05+195.15+198.43+183.594+170.9+155.5)/6
and so on for each year.  In the end there would be as many rows as there are years left (from 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014.

[image]

Resulting dataframe would look like...

[image]

Comment: `df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year)['Mean'].agg('mean')` if I understand you correctly.

Comment: This works but doesn't return a proper pandas dataframe.  how do I change that?

Comment: add a `.reset_index()` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: first you get the years and after you can get the average based on a search.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ds = pd.DataFrame([['2019-01-1', 1], ['2019-02-1' , 2], ['2018-01-1', 3], 
                   ['2018-02-1' , 4]], columns=['data', 'mean'])


#get year
d = ds.data.tolist()

years = [x.split('-')[0] for x in d]
ds['year'] = years #add the year to the dataset

#get the mean
ds2 = pd.DataFrame(None, columns=['year', 'mean'])
for y in set(years):
    avg = np.average(ds[ds.year == y]['mean'])
    row = pd.DataFrame([[y, avg]], columns=['year', 'mean'])
    ds2 = ds2.append(row)
```